# Xcode 5 - Can't find static library

Tags: xcode

I'm new at Xcode, just tried to create a static library, and it got built okay. However I can't seem to add it to the other target because it doesn't show up in 'Link Library With Libraries" , project folder is not showing up there either. This is pretty simple but can't figure it out?

Comment: I see it under Product folder and it's not in red.

Comment: What happens when you try to add it to the "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase?

Comment: The problem is I can't add it there because it's not listed. It's only listed on Project list under Product...